# Passing event to JavaScript function in external js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have function which open window pop on click event. These functions are on external js files.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.cart-window').click(open);
    
    function open (){
        // function perform
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    }   
});
```

Everything work fine, but when I re-initiate this function (`$('a.cart-window').click(open);`) in response of ajax success call to implement this function on newly generated html, it wont work. Firebug shows an error:

> NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object

What I am just trying to do is that, I have lots of lengthy JS functions and give them a name like open as I show in the above code and call it from anywhere so I don't need to write full code in an ajax success response. Important note: I use `$(this)` in my functions and also want to pass event to function.

ajax code:

```
function callAjax() {

    $.ajax({
        url: ,
        type: "POST",
        data: 
    }).done(function (msg) {
  
   $('a.cart-window').click(open);
    
    });
}
```

Comment: I see you have asked 9 questions but haven't marked any of them as answered nor cast a vote on any of them. Maybe you could let the people who answered your question know if it helped you. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I will marked next time, I didn't know before because i dont know how it work. Thanks again for telling me.

Comment: No problem, thank you for marking the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are dealing with dynamic elements, use event delegation(using event propagation) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a.cart-window', open);

    function open (){
        // function perform
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    }   
});
```

In this case there is no need to re-initiate the event handlers for the newly updated dom.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I always confused where and when .on() method should use. Anyways thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.cart-window').on('click',function(e){open(e)});
    function open (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // function perform
        var loginBox = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');// you can use e.currentTarget here
        return false;
    }   
});
```